# variable changes inside while block but code stuck in loop

Tags: loops, while-loop, pine-script

Does anyone have any idea why this piece of code is stuck in a loop?

```
var stochRsiCross=false

if under20 and stochRsiCrossover
    stochRsiCross:=true
    while stochRsiCross
        if cciCrossover
            strategy.order("buy",strategy.long)
            stochRsiCross:=false
```

What I want this code to do is when `StochRsi` is under 20 and cross occurs, wait for `CCI` cross to occur. I don't know it actually do this or not because it gives the stuck in loop error.

Comment: How do you know that the variable's value change?

Comment: Also, this code will not work. That's not how `pinescript` works. I suggest you start [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/index.html).

Comment: @vitruvius inside of last if,  `stochRsiCross:=false`

Comment: @vitruvius  `if cciCrossover` may not true on current candle. so it stuck. I think I should not use `while`

Answer (score 0):

From these piece of code when your `under20 and stochRsiCrossover` is true you get into while loop and if `cciCrossover` is false, you never get the line with `stochRsiCross:=false` that stop the loop